# How to prevent the dialog that shows the available wireless networks to show twice?

Tags: macos, airport

Whenever none of my preferred wifi networks is available and my Airport is turned on a dialog appears that shows all the available networks at the moment. That is as expected.
However, when I exit that dialog as I don't want to connect to a wifi network, it dissappears, the Airport menu icon shows that it's looking for networks again and the dialog appears again. This is annoying.

How can I prevent the dialog from appearing a second time? Turning off the dialog completely would be viable as well as I almost never use it anyway and can have the same functionality through the Airport menu item.

I'm on a MacBook Pro 5,3 (Mid 2009) with Mac OSX 10.8.4.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open System Preferences, go to networks, select Airport and make sure the "Ask to join new networks" check is not selected.

[image]

This will suppress the dialog all the time as there isn't an easy way to have it suppress a second dialog in a timeframe or after a disconnect event.

Comment: This works, thank you. Is there a reason I get to see the dialog twice? I can't recall this was the case several months ago.

Comment: I don't have a good answer other than it's being more eager to get you to join? Do you have two WiFi interfaces in the left side of the pane perhaps?

Comment: Nope, only Wi-Fi interface.